# Navigation block is rendered twice?

Tags: magento, templates

i try to include a custom category-navigation in the left column of a custom magento layout template. there fore i placed the following code in my `local.xml`

```
<!--Category View-->
<catalog_category_view>
    <!--Set Page Template-->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/hew_layout_2cl.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.catleftnav" template="catalog/category/navigation/left.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```

my layout file is placed in `design/frontend/###CUSTOM###/default/template/page/layout_2cl.phtml` and includes the following line for the left column

```
<div class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
```

the left.phtml navigation file is placed in `design/frontend/###CUSTOM###/default/template/catalog/category/navigation/left.phtml` and looks like this

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <?php if ($currentCategory && $currentCategory->getId() == $_category->getId()): ?>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

the only problem here is, that the left block is rendered twice. i also followed the bugfix of the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294668/magento-custom-left-navigation-template-displaying-twice), but it didn't help.

any advice on this? thanks!

Comment: Have you unset or removed the native left catalog nav yet? I see it's a custom block name you're calling in here in local.xml, if catalog.xml is still pulling in the native block name then you will naturally have both loaded onto the front end.

Comment: yeah, unsetting the block first works! thanks…